# bash script skipping section

Tags: bash, sequential

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
  do "curl http://192.168.1.2/api/queue | grep -q $3"
    case ${PIPESTATUS[*]} in
      "0 1")
        echo "Queue is no longer in the queue." > /config/log.txt
        break;;
      "0 0")
        echo "Queue is still in the queue. Trying again in 5 minutes." > /config/log.txt
        sleep 5;;
      "7 1")
        echo "Server is unreachable. Trying again in 5 minutes." > /config/log.txt
        sleep 5m;;
    esac
  done

case $2 in
  testvalue1)
      curl -i --data "hashes=$3&category=testcat"  http://localhost:8082/command/setCategory
      ;; 
  *)
      echo "Deleting $4." > /config/log.txt
      curl -i --data "hashes=$3" http://localhost:8082/command/deletePerm
      ;;
esac
```

There are two parts to the script. The first part queries a queue on on server and if the queue is empty moves on to the second part. The second part will check for a certain value and if it is there ti will issue a curl command, or if it is anything else it will issue another command.

The issue is that both the two sections of the script work fine as seperate scripts but not together. Once I combine them, the first part is skipped entirely, or so it seems. It is supposed to wait for the queue to be empty from the first part and then proceed to the second part but for some reason it is just going straight to the second part. I added those outputs to file and they never get created. Any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: I just tried it again and the opposite happened. The first part executed but the second did not. I'm so confused.

Comment: Now neither are executing...

Comment: You should be getting an error, since there is almost certainly no command by the name of `curl http://192.168.1.1/api/queue | grep -q $3` (depending on what `$3` actually expands to). The double quotes should not be there.

Comment: The script is called automatically by a program so I can't see the output. I executed it manually with the parameters and it gave me a "no such file or directory" error and, yes, the double quotes was the issue. I originally did not have quotes but I used shellcheck.net to check my syntax and it suggested I "Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting". Can you clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: Double quote *parameter expansions*, not entire command lines.